# Scroll down button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've already created the #scrolldownbutton to scroll to the first component but what I'm initially trying to do is when the button is clicked the page scrolls within the viewport and stops on the partially visible component at the bottom of the view port in which the button should appear at the the top of the visible component and the bottom of the viewport each time the button is clicked.

Here is what I have so far Please if anyone could help this would be amazing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#scrollmorebutton").on("click", function() {

      console.log("scrollmorebutton was clicked");

  //jquery smooth scroll code here

      $('html, body').animate({

        scrollTop: $("h2:contains('New Programs')").offset().top

      }, 2000);

    });

});
```

Comment: Are you trying to have a *jump to {div name}* feature?

Comment: If that works, I've never used a jump to {div name} feature this is all new to me

Comment: I'll post an answer in the morning. I'm currently on my mobile. Just a note, my solution won't have any JavaScript.

Comment: A link pointing to an HTML div ID.

Comment: so after the button is clicked and the page scrolls to the first component which will be an HTML div ID will that still allow the scroll down button to show on the next div ID/component so it can be clicked again to scroll to the next and the next?

Answer (score 1):

Might not be anything near what you're asking for as i'm not entirely sure I understand. But here's a fiddle with some `example code`

https://jsfiddle.net/cf3q2zo9/

Comment: Yes, but the button has to show on the next component so it can click to the next one.

Comment: @Code4life Can you not just add more buttons?

Comment: I'm using a sprite for the button